# "Table Storage Engine Doesn't have this option" Error in ALTER Query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am Executing the the below query to disable the key constraints. I am using MariaDB 5.4

```
alter table table_name disable keys
```

But it produces a warning as below:

> Table Storage Engine for table_name Doesn't have this option.

I am having Inno_DB as engine. I don't understand why this warning is coming and the key constraints are not disabled.

How can I solve this error ? Or is there any other way to disable the key constraints?

Comment: Let's back up a step and discuss your task that involves disabling keys.  Performance in some way?  Modifying something?  What?

Comment: I have a task running which fails because updation of table fails due to primary key constraint. I know its not valid scenario to insert duplicate values for keys but I have no another option.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the 'updation' statement leading to the issue.  It may be helpful for us to see the indexes, collations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From the MariaDB documentation on [`ALTER TABLE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-table/#enable-disable-keys):

> `DISABLE KEYS` will disable all non unique keys for the table for
>   storage engines that support this (at least MyISAM and Aria).

In other words, as the warning suggests, this option is not available for InnoDB.

Comment: I am looking for a way to disable the primary key constraint check, is there any way to do it ?

Comment: @HardRocker Drop the constraint and recreate it later. Or just avoid having to drop it at all?

Answer (score 0):

If using InnoDB and using a script from mysqldump with multiple enable/ disable keys statements the script will throw warnings because these statements are not supported. It may also fail on lines such as

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MyTable`;
```

due to foreign key constraints.

The scripts can be made to work by running the following command in a sql script tab (there will still be warnings due to enable/disable keys lines, but it shouldn't stop the script from running to completion).

```
set foreign_key_checks = OFF;
```

Then after running the scripts the foreign key checks should be re-enabled

```
set foreign_key_checks = ON;
```